# PostGIS Geometry folder is missing

Tags: postgis, geometry

I have installed PostgreSQL 9.2 and PostGIS 2.0.3 from Stackbuilder. My template_postgis_20 does not have a geometry table only spatial_ref_sys table.

Is that a problem and, if not, then how can i create table using this postgis template with Geometry?

I have both tried Windows 7 and 8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should not be a geometry *table* so there should be no problem. You will want a table  that has a geometry *column* though. Actually, `geometry` is the *data type*, and the column that is of that type can have any name -- the name, however, is conventionally called "geom" or sometimes "the_geom".

You use the template_postgis only when you create a spatial database:

Assuming you're using pgAdmin III,

```
Object browser > Server Groups > Servers > PostgreSQL (localhost:5432) > Databases
```

(From now on, this will be just `pgAdmin: >>> Databases`)

```
pgAdmin: >>> Databases R-mouse-btn> New Database

Properties
    Name: my_new_db
    Owner: postgres
Definition
    Template: template_postgis
```

That last bit is important; it ensures that the DB is spatially enabled.

```
OK
```

Now go examine your new DB.

```
pgAdmin: >>> Databases > my_new_db > Schemas > public
```

Notice the counts for the new "empty" DB are all (0), except Functions (approx. 892), Tables (1), Views (4) -- thus, it's spatially enabled.